# Share project to GitHub from IDEA: How add all project to repository into branch named "lab1"

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

My account in GitHub doen`t have the repository so I use git command:

```
$ git push -u origin main:lab1
```

Well.. created a repository, and created 1 branch: lab1(((
But I must have

**2 branches:**

1. main with README.md
2. **lab1 with project** (NOT in commit)

*Please, help me*

Comment: Your question needs some more detail. You're looking for 2 branches, (main) with just a readme.md file and (lab1) with the rest of the code. That part is understood, but what do you mean by "NOT in commit"? It sounds like there is a basic misunderstanding of how git operates. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: I don`t know how, but part of my attempts ended the project files to commit (how a comment) under of the branch, no in branch

Comment: If you have a project,  and you choose "Share project to GitHub" you will be prompted to choose configuration for future repository, then choose files for initial commit. Once it's done, you can switch to Lab1 branch and push it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax to rename a branch.
You should do

```
git checkout -b [yourbranchname]
git push origin [yourbranchname]
```